# Magento Error: Cannot send headers error in Collection.php

Tags: magento, header

In my Magento 1.6.2.0 I get an error when exporting the customers:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:156:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in .../Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Entity/Attribute/Option/Collection.php, line 1";i:1;s:1385:"
#0 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 .../Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(105): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('http://mysite...', 302)
#2 .../Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(336): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('http://mysite...')
#3 .../Mage/ImportExport/controllers/Adminhtml/ExportController.php(98): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->_redirect('*/*/index')
#4 .../Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ExportController->exportAction()
#5 .../Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('export')
#6 .../Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 .../Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /home/mysite/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}";s:3:"url";s:99:"/index.php/admin/export/export/key/.../entity/customer/file_format/csv";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Same Error after saving a new or edited product. The product is saved but before there is an error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:156:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in .../core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Entity/Attribute/Option/Collection.php, line 1";i:1;s:1420:"
#0 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 .../core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(105): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('http://mysite...', 302)
#2 .../core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(336): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('http://mysite...')
#3 .../local/CJM/ColorSelectorPlus/controllers/Override/Admin/Catalog/ProductController.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->_redirect('*/*/', Array)
#4 .../core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): CJM_ColorSelectorPlus_Override_Admin_Catalog_ProductController->saveAction()
#5 .../core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#6 .../core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 .../core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /home/mysite/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}";s:3:"url";s:82:"/index.php/admin/catalog_product/save/id/246/key/.../";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

> Cannot send headers; headers already sent...

...means that there is a header redirect but there was an output before. But where the hell can that be in core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Entity/Attribute/Option/Collection.php ?

Some ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Stephan,Have you tried disabling all your custom extensions ? It looks like something is throwing an error that isn't catched properly and Magento is throwing a fit because some data is displayed before the headers are set

Comment: I disabled all the extensions. Still the same error. I found out that I get the same error when updating the search index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it and it's stupid. I was confused beacause of

`Cannot send headers; headers already sent in .../Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Entity/Attribute/Option/Collection.php, line 1`

headers already sent in ... Line 1. It was a encoding error of the file. So, if you're working with notepadd++ don't forget to use utf-8 with BOM, it saves you a lot of time searching for wired errors.